# Renaming a git repository, local and distant

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Bitbucket is essentially for me a versioning tool for security reason, no one work on those repos except me.
I have a local project, stored in a local directory.
The directory was created empty, then i cloned inside a local repository named A from a distant one (on bitbucket).

I work locally, and i commit/push using sourcetree.

I would need to rename a project, which would mean :

- renaming local folder
- renaming local repo
- renaming distant repo
- correct local-distant association in sourcetree

Would anyone have a bulletproof method for that ?

N.B. : I'm a git user, which is why i'm using sourcetree, not a git superstar knowing all the commands and options :)

Comment: It can be easy though. You can change the name of repo online on github account via settings. And refactor rename the project within IDE. It will rename all the references and then push the changes to github

Comment: @ImranFaruqi The OP uses BitBucket, not GitHub.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A repo doesn't know its name. The only "link" you would have to update is : in your local configuration of `remote` repositories, you would have to update the url to push to/pull from (which *does* mention the repo name on bitucket).

Taking back your list of steps :

- renaming local folder : rename it as you would rename a regular folder ; then open that new folder in Sourcetree
- renaming local repo : noop
- renaming distant repo : rename it on bitbucket
- correct local-distant association in sourcetree :
  thechnically that link is stored in your local repo, in the `.git/config` file
  you can update it from the command line :

  ```
   git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/url/to/newname
  ```

  Sourcetree probably has a settings screen where you can apply the same action ; this setting is obviously a per repo setting, do not look for it in some "global settings" or "global preferences" section.

Run a simple `git fetch` to check that the url is correctly registered.

Comment: I will test it asap. Thanks a lot.